# Unable to access [object FormData] stored in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yui

I have called an AJAX with some post fields like this:

```
var postData ="gid="+gid+"&daydob=" +daydob+"&monthdob=" +monthdob;
```

With reference to [THIS](https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/) blog, for a FILE I have done something like this:

```
var fileId = document.getElementById("fileGS");                 
var file = fileId.files[0];                 
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
```

Finally:

```
postData = postData + "&fileGS=" + formData;
//Called AJAX after
```

Now while retrieving the parameter `fileGS`, I get `[object FormData]` in a PHP variable, where I am unable to access this JS object for uploading my File using PHP.

Can anyone please help me out that how can I access this object. I cannot alter much this AJAX since it is already in production(and uses `YAHOO YUI`). I am only adding image uploading feature to it.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but as a suggestion you may pass form data in JSON format and parse it in PHP form. Eg:- `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(form_data))`. In this case you won't get this format **[object FormData]**

Comment: Bro is this will help me in accessing file in the back-end for uploading?

Comment: My try is to resolve your issue of getting the parameters in the form in proper format rather than **[object FormData]**